# How can I copy a part of a string from a column into a new column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string

I have a column with a date range nested in a string and I need to retrieve the start and end date and place them in a new column. Below is an example of what the data looks like.

```
A               
foo_bar_2/27-6/30    
bar_foo_3/07-4/01    
foo_bar_6/19-7/30
```

I need to extract those dates and I can't split on indexes because some of the dates are different lengths ie: 12/27 vs 1/7. They are, however, in the same format (_startdate-enddate). How can I get the start and end date and put them in their own column? Example below:

```
A                   start_date  end_date
foo_bar_2/27-6/30     2/27       6/30
bar_foo_3/7-4/1       3/7        4/1    
foo_bar_6/19-7/30     6/19       7/30
```

Any advice helps

Comment: You should also invest time with the [Pandas User Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df[['start_date', 'end_date']] = df['A'].str.extract("(?P<start_date>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2})-(?P<end_date>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2})", expand=True)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
                   A start_date end_date
0  foo_bar_2/27-6/30       2/27     6/30
1  bar_foo_3/07-4/01       3/07     4/01
2  foo_bar_6/19-7/30       6/19     7/30
```

As an alternative:

```
df[['start_date', 'end_date']] = df['A'].str.extract("(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2})", expand=True)
```

Finally if the patterns are like in the sample input, split by `_` or `-`, and take the last two elements:

```
df[['start_date', 'end_date']] = df['A'].str.split('[_-]', expand=True).iloc[:, -2:]
```

Comment: This is great, works like a charm. Looks like I need to do some more research on extract so I can continue to use it. Thanks!